# sIFR only works partially in IE due to conflict with jQuery

Tags: jquery, flash, sifr, conflict, sifr3

My sIFR 3 font replacement is working great in FF and IE except when I use it on a 'services' page that has an unrelated Flash object feature at the bottom. Only the first sIFR3'ed element shows up in IE on this page. I am also using jQuery 1.2.6 on this page to bring up random content. It is a windows xp pc.

In IE, the html on the 'services'page sIFR'ed elements has become garbled in the browser as I see when I view the source. Things like this: nodeIndex='1' and jQuery1307565945701='4' are added to the ul and li elements and should not be. The class 'sIFR-replaced' is not being added from sIFR like it is supposed to be.

The jQuery does not interfere with sIFR3 font replacement on my other pages because they don't have the extra Flash file on the bottom. The Flash file is a shockwave cab file, version 9,0,0,0 (that I did not add).

I see this error in the console ' 'match(...).1' is null or not an object' but I got this same error elsewhere and it wasn't affecting anything.

I'm really stuck on this one. I tried to load things at different times and I added other fixes but no luck. Thanks for any help you can give me with this. I am a beginner at all of this.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, leave sIFR. It's old and outdated and just not good. You could try [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) or if you can pay money, use [typekit](http://www.typekit.com)